# Use DATA step vs PROC IMPORT

Tags: sas

In SAS, while creating a SAS data set from a raw data file (csv), we can either use the `DATA` step with the `infile` keyword or the `PROC IMPORT` step.
What are the advantages and disadvantages of each over the other?

Comment: Lists of advantages/disadvantages aren't really on topic for this site ("list questions").  I think a more well tailored question would be on topic, though.

Comment: In particular, if you're looking for something specific about one _or_ the other, asking about that might be on topic.  Right now it's just too broad and too much discussion-oriented.  A good question should come from a specific use case, or at least a more-or-less specific use case; so, a question with some detail about a potential use case would be appropriate.

Comment: Also - see [this meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258308/asking-questions-about-advantages-disadvantages-on-so) for more detail.

Comment: Basically, I wanted to know while reading a file, if I should use proc or data step.

Comment: If you are asking about reading a _particular_ file, then you should post the relevant details related to that file, plus the process overall (is this a one-time read in, is this a production process, can the file change in contents, things like that).  If you're asking for a generic 'file', that question is not a good fit for our site.

Comment: Use a data step. Proc import allows SAS to determine the variable types, it guesses, smart guesses, but not always correct. Using a data step you have to specify the formats/types and that will ensure your data is read correctly and consistently. However, it's not necessarily a either/or, I usually use proc import to start off my data step and then modify the code as needed rather than start from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proc Import makes assumptions about the lengths of character variables and types of variables based on reading a number of rows in the CSV which is controlled by an option.  If you issue a recall command in interactive sas after running proc import you get the data step code that proc import generated to do the actual work.  It generates format and informat statements that may or may not be exactly what you want.

I often use proc import as a data step code generator, recall the code, and then modify it to suit what I want.

You can also add other processing logic to extend the functionality of the step beyond simply reading the source data into a data set. Creating new variables as transformations of one or more of the columns in the CSV springs to mind.

Answer (score 0):

I generally agree this is too broad a question.  That said:

PROC IMPORT is slower than a DATA STEP.  This is because PROC IMPORT looks at the file and then writes and executes a DATA STEP.

A DATA STEP requires you to know the name, position, and attributes (type, length, etc) for each variable.

If I need to read a file once, I just use PROC IMPORT.

If I need to read a file multiple times, I don't care about speed, and the file format might change, then I use PROC IMPORT.

If I am in a production system where speed matters and I want an ERROR if the format changes, then I use PROC IMPORT.  But I take the DATA STEP it writes for me and put that into my code.

If PROC IMPORT fails to guess my columns correctly, I use PROC IMPORT, modify the DATA STEP it produces, and then use that.